# metroColorStyle is a type and can not be used as an expression error

Tags: vb.net

I was inspired by this c# function:.

```
private void metroTileSwitch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var m = new Random();
        int next = m.Next(0, 13);
        metroStyleManager.Style = (MetroColorStyle)next;
    }
```

I tried to replicate the function in vb.net importing the objects of the framework:

```
 Dim m = New Random()
 Dim s = m.Next(0, 13)
 Form1.MetroStyleManager1.Style = (MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle)s 'there's an error here
```

but i have a problem with the last line, in particular, the compiler tells me that:

"metroColorStyle is a type in MetrFramework and can not be used as an expression".

Why this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in C#:

```
metroStyleManager.Style = (MetroColorStyle)next;
```

Translates in VB to:

```
metroStyleManager.Style = DirectCast(s, MetroColorStyle)
' or if you have not imported the NameSpace:
metroStyleManager.Style = DirectCast(s, MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle)
```

There are several good online converters which will do this.  Whatever `m` is will have to be a Type which can be cast to `MetroColorStyle`.

Comment: The code now is not from syntax errors but when I click on the button that has that feature built-in color is not changed why?

Comment: we have no idea what `M` is or holds, we have no idea if the original code does what you want or if you have code elsewhere breaking it.  We fixed your error, the rest sounds like a new question.

Answer (score 0):

On vb.net:

1. If you successfully imported all the metro controls, find in the list the "metrostylemanager" and after add it to your form it will appear as `"MetroStyleManager1"` exactly like adding a timer.
2. then select it `("MetroStyleManager1")` and modify its properties to

   > "modifiers: public" & "Owner: select your form"
3. the way i'm changing the colors (no need to import anything):

   > MetroStyleManager1.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Red

Hope this helps